# Moment Of Inertia of half cylinder

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions, physics

With cylinder I have:

```
 body = Cylinder[{{-l/2, 0, 0}, {l/2, 0, 0}}, r];
 (\[ScriptCapitalI] = \[Rho] MomentOfInertia[body, 
 Assumptions -> l > 0 && w > 0 && h > 0]) // MatrixForm; 
 m Cancel[\[ScriptCapitalI]/(\[Rho] Volume[body])] // MatrixForm(*Code from MMA help*)

 (*{{(m*r^2)/2, 0, 0}, {0, (m*(l^2 + 3*r^2))/12, 0}, {0, 0, (m*(l^2 + 3*r^2))/12}}*)
```

But how do this with  half cylinder?
[image]

Comment: Replace `body` with `DiscretizeRegion[Cylinder[], {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]`

Comment: @N.J.Evans.Yes works ,but I what solutions with:`l`,`m` ,`r` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Takes a few seconds, but `ImplicitRegion` works:

```
body = ImplicitRegion[
  y^2 + z^2 <= r^2 && z >= 0 && -L/2 <= x <= L/2, {x, y, z}]
(ℐ = ρ MomentOfInertia[body, 
     Assumptions -> L > 0 && r > 0]) // MatrixForm
m Cancel[ℐ/(ρ Volume[body, 
       Assumptions -> r > 0 && L > 0])] // MatrixForm
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The representation `body = RegionIntersection[Cylinder[{{-L/2, 0, 0}, {L/2, 0, 0}}, r], HalfSpace[{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 0}]]` also works.

Comment: @J.M.'sennui I tried that, but the integral didn't finish. Maybe I didn't wait long enough.

Comment: @J.M.'sennui OK, it doesn't take longer than it takes to go get a cup of coffee. :)